# do-release-upgrade from 18.04 aborting

Tags: upgrade

- [main.log](https://pastebin.com/D8eWcib8)

```
2024-03-01 14:10:09,360 INFO Using config files '['./DistUpgrade.cfg.bionic', '/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades.d/ubuntu-advantage-upgrades.cfg']'
2024-03-01 14:10:09,360 INFO uname information: 'Linux pruttel 4.15.0-213-generic #224-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jun 19 13:30:12 UTC 2023 x86_64'
2024-03-01 14:10:09,891 INFO apt version: '1.6.17'
2024-03-01 14:10:09,892 INFO python version: '3.6.9 (default, Mar 10 2023, 16:46:00) 
[GCC 8.4.0]'
2024-03-01 14:10:09,896 INFO release-upgrader version '20.04.40' started
2024-03-01 14:10:09,911 INFO locale: 'en_US' 'UTF-8'
2024-03-01 14:10:09,976 INFO screen could not be run
2024-03-01 14:10:10,017 DEBUG Using 'DistUpgradeViewText' view
2024-03-01 14:10:10,075 DEBUG enable dpkg --force-overwrite
2024-03-01 14:10:10,126 DEBUG creating statefile: '/var/log/dist-upgrade/apt-clone_system_state.tar.gz'
2024-03-01 14:10:15,862 DEBUG lsb-release: 'bionic'
2024-03-01 14:10:15,863 DEBUG _pythonSymlinkCheck run
2024-03-01 14:10:15,867 DEBUG openCache()
2024-03-01 14:10:15,867 DEBUG quirks: running PreCacheOpen
2024-03-01 14:10:15,867 DEBUG running Quirks.PreCacheOpen
2024-03-01 14:10:17,460 DEBUG Comparing 4.15.0-212 with 
2024-03-01 14:10:17,460 DEBUG Comparing 4.15.0-213 with 4.15.0-212
2024-03-01 14:10:18,030 DEBUG /openCache(), new cache size 116775
2024-03-01 14:10:18,030 DEBUG need_server_mode(): run in 'desktop' mode, (because of key deps for 'ubuntu-desktop')
2024-03-01 14:10:18,030 DEBUG checkViewDepends()
2024-03-01 14:10:18,035 DEBUG running doUpdate() (showErrors=False)
2024-03-01 14:10:20,584 DEBUG openCache()
2024-03-01 14:10:22,211 DEBUG Comparing 4.15.0-212 with 
2024-03-01 14:10:22,211 DEBUG Comparing 4.15.0-213 with 4.15.0-212
2024-03-01 14:10:22,802 DEBUG /openCache(), new cache size 116775
2024-03-01 14:10:22,803 DEBUG doPostInitialUpdate
2024-03-01 14:10:22,803 DEBUG quirks: running focalPostInitialUpdate
2024-03-01 14:10:22,803 DEBUG running Quirks.focalPostInitialUpdate
2024-03-01 14:10:25,242 DEBUG abort called
2024-03-01 14:10:25,242 DEBUG openCache()
2024-03-01 14:10:26,879 DEBUG Comparing 4.15.0-212 with 
2024-03-01 14:10:26,879 DEBUG Comparing 4.15.0-213 with 4.15.0-212
2024-03-01 14:10:27,452 DEBUG /openCache(), new cache size 116775
```

- [apt.log](https://pastebin.com/JCnMZtUx)

```
Log time: 2024-03-01 14:10:18.023495
Log time: 2024-03-01 14:10:22.784019
Log time: 2024-03-01 14:10:27.445820
```

Upgrading from 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS gives the following output:

```
$ sudo do-release-upgrade 
[sudo] password for marijn: 
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [1554 B]                                          
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1338 kB]                                                   
Fetched 1340 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                  
authenticate 'focal.tar.gz' against 'focal.tar.gz.gpg' 
extracting 'focal.tar.gz'

Reading cache

Checking package manager
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Hit http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                       
Hit http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease               
Hit http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease              
Hit http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease             
Hit https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie InRelease    
Fetched 0 B in 0s (0 B/s)                                                      
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done

Restoring original system state

Aborting
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done
$
```

The log files (see above) also give no indication why the process is aborting. The system is up-to-date (within 18.04 at least). How do I figure out what the problem is?

Comment: do see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1344069/cant-upgrade-to-ubuntu-21-04-restoring-original-system-state-aborting I assume you need to purge packagecloud.io

Comment: Hmm, somewhat plausible, but it keeps doing stuff for several seconds after that.

Comment: probably more 3rd party apps? those need to go before an upgrade

Comment: Removing packagecloud.io from sources.list.d did not help. (There was already no package installed from there anymore.)

snapd, from the question you linked, may be a culprit. snapd on my system has trouble mounting things. I'll look into that.

Comment: Removing snapd helped. Thanks for the link. (Note that my initial response was to an earlier version of your first comment, which did not contain that link.)

Comment: excellent; though this will get closed as a dupe ;)

Comment: Ah, I remember again, your first comment was initially about "Fetched 0 kB in 0s (0 B/s)". Please do not edit comments to completely change their meaning, it confuses the heck out of everyone.

Comment: But yes, my question is essentially a duplicate. The symptoms were the same as in the linked question.